# Java method overloading - two lists

Tags: java, overloading

I'd like to ask how can I overload java method like this:

```
    public static int printAll(List<Class1> list) {
        int i = 0;
        for (Class1 e: list) {
                System.out.println(e.getName());
        }

        return i;
    }

    public static int printAll(List<Class2> list) {
        int i = 0;
        for (Class2 e: list) {
            System.out.println(e.getName());
        }
        return i;
    }
```

Both `Class1` and `Class2` have method `getName()` implemented.

Thank you

Comment: Are `Class1` and `Class2` related in any way? e.g., do they implement the same interface? Or *should* they?

Comment: Unluckily they are not related in any way

Comment: Whats the reason behind returning `i` ?  The value of i is always 0?

Comment: What's the point of having two identical methods?

Comment: I just copy pasted my code and forgot to remove that return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it be acceptable for the caller to have to pass in an additional parameter for how to get the name from the objects in the list? You could use something like this:

```
public static <T> int printAll(List<T> list, Function<T, String> nameExtractor) {
    int i = 0;
    for (T e: list) {
        System.out.println(nameExtractor.apply(e));
    }
    return i;
}
```

Then you can call it as:

```
printAll(list1, Class1::getName);
```

Or:

```
printAll(list2, Class2::getName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface and implement it for Class1 and Class2

```
interface IClass {
   String getName();
}

class Class1 implements IClass {
     //your implementation
}

class Class2 implements IClass {
     //your implementation
}
```

And use it in your method signature

```
public static int printAll(List<IClass> list) {
    int i = 0;
    for (IClass e: list) {
        System.out.println(e.getName());
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: I thought about it too, but my project doesn’t allow me to do this

Answer (score 0):

In java, Generic Types does not exist in runtime and they are erased by something called `Type Erasure`. So defining two such methods will give you a compile-time error saying that both methods clashes with each other and `both have the same erasure`. However, if you want to do this anyway there are some ways to do this. One of them is already on @Lungu Daniel's answer. You can also change on of `List<Class2> list` parameters to another collection type like this:

```
public static int printAll(LinkedList<Class1> list) {//You will have to cast it to LinkedList
    int i = 0;
    for (Class1 e: list) {
            System.out.println(e.getName());
    }

    return i;
}

public static int printAll(List<Class2> list) {
    int i = 0;
    for (Class2 e: list) {
        System.out.println(e.getName());
    }
    return i;
}
public static int printAll(Class3[] list) {//It can be an array too.
    int i = 0;
    for (Class3 e: list) {
        System.out.println(e.getName());
    }
    return i;
}
```